# How to edit a document value to a specific URL? (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, return-type

I understand that

> num: document.images.length

returns the number of images on a webpage...
however what exactly is "document"
I don't have any files labeled document so I'm assuming this is an internal code demand.

Basically I want to display the number of images on one specific webpage only. So I want to change the value of document to Flickr.Com.

How do I reset the value of document to a URL?
This is for a chrome extension.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document

Answer (score 1):

document is the javascript object version of the page.

[Here is a good starter article.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp)

You **cannot** set the document object to a specific url.

If you want to load another document, you can use an invisible [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp)  and set the iframe src to the page you want to load. Then, find the iframe with javascript/jquery and the iframe content should be the document object of that page.